# Storing Photos library on Time Machine external hard drive with partitioning

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, partition

I have a Photos library on my Mac, which I want to move to an external hard drive in order to save space on my computer's internal hard drive.

I want to move the library to the same drive I use for Time Machine backups.

However, this link says it cannot be done: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201517.

> 1. You can't move your library to a disk that's used for Time Machine backups.

But I assume that means the same volume. If I were to add a second partition to the disk, just for file storage – leaving the first partition for Time Machine backups – would I be able to move the Photos library to this second partition, as well as other files like iTunes library and documents?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a Time Machine drive have several partitions, or does Time Machine need the whole HDD to itself?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85627/can-a-time-machine-drive-have-several-partitions-or-does-time-machine-need-the) and [can-i-use-a-large-external-hard-drive-both-as-installation-media-and-backup-driv](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177955/can-i-use-a-large-external-hard-drive-both-as-installation-media-and-backup-driv?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @ankiiiiiii Thank you for the links, the first one answered my question.